# FMOD gvraudio.bundle for Mac

Tags: google-vr, fmod

I'm trying to work with GVR audio plugins through FMOD in my Mac but am unable to find the gvraudio.bundle binary that one is instructed to import into the plugins folder of the Unity project in order to get things running. It is simply not in the GVR FMOD package. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

When you download the unitypackage fmodstudio10901-v2.unitypackage from FMOD www.fmod.org/download/, and import the package into Unity through 
Assets > Import Package > Custom Package

The gvraudio.bundle will be present in your project folder, and viewable with finder under
Assets/Plugins/gvraudio.bundle

This happens automatically when you Import FMOD's unitypackage.